# While using the switch statement my compiler is throwing warning of case label value exceeds maximum value for type case Mumbai and not printing o/p

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
char city;
 switch (city)
    {
    case 'Mumbai':
        printf("Enter 1 to see the cinemas\n");
        printf("Enter 2 to see the movies which are currently in cinemas\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        switch (num)
        {
        case 1:
            // Create function
            //  Taking the names of cinemas from file
            printf("Cinema\n");
        case 2:
            // Create function
            //  Taking the names of movies from file
            printf("Movies\n");
        }
```

Comment: Do you know what a `char` is vs what a string is in C? Perhaps you want `city` to be a string. In which case it should be `char *city` or `char city[MAX_LEN]` (depending on how you want to store the string which you have not shown). Then need to use `strcmp` and not `switch` to compare for the strings you want to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single-quotes declare a character in C. Unlike Python, where they can be used for strings C doesn't allow multiple characters between ''. That's the source of your issue.

You need to use double quotes for strings (""). C doesn't natively support strings so it uses a pointer to the first character as a string type, it is declared like `char *`. You can also use array of characters `char str[]`.

You might consider learning about pointers in C and cstrings, because as suggested in the comments you seem to be confused too much to pinpoint or direct you in a single direction.

In C there's no simple way to do switch on strings. You'd use `strcmp` function to compare strings (the function returns 0 when the strings are equal).

```
char *city = ...;
if(strcmp(city, "mumbai") == 0) {
  // ...
}
else if(strcmp(city, "moscow") == 0) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: C does allow multi-character character constants (see [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4)), but the value of such a constant is implementation-defined and hence non-portable.  You're correct that such constants probably don't mean what the OP expects, and that character strings are much more likely candidates.

Comment: In addition to being wrong about C not allowing multiple characters inside `''`, this answer does not answer the question asked, why the warning states “case label value exceeds maximum value.”